Xcode Cloud: Unit tests are always failing with same "No such module" error
I have unit tests that are working fine when running locally. However, when I try to add a test action on Xcode Cloud on a specific tag and run it, the test fails on Xcode Cloud. Knowing that I have build and archive actions that works fine.
Here is my Test Action:

and here is the error I see:

In SplashScreenViewModelUnitTest I have the following line of code:
@testable import MY_PROJECT_NAME

I tried even to replace the Test with "Use Scheme Settings" where I have my unit test plan added, but getting same error.

"No such module" is seems to be compile time issue. When you push your code into cloud thier might be chances of your code isn't properly linked with your target. Check XCode settings your test class file properly linked with your target.

Can you be more specific in what I should be looking for in settings? @Rajendra
